# How to load application specific jar files in the Glassfish server 4.1

Tags: java, lucene, glassfish-4

Currently i am working on one application related to document search using lucene. On my Local System the application is running properly. But When i tried to integrate the application with the organization web application the application is not running.
The problem is that organization web application is old one and is using the old libraries "Xerces" and it's getting the conflict and if replace the old "Xerces" libraries with new one "Xerces" the application is not starting since some of the modules are using old one.

Now i think is there some way through which i can create one more application with it's set of libraries in glassfish server so that both the application runs without conflict within the domain1.

Also if there is any better way please suggest me how to proceed

Comment: what is the specific version  of Glassfish you are running?

Comment: glassfish 4.1 server

Comment: then the problem lies out of the Glassfish you are running. I bumped into such problems when I installed glassfish v4.1.11 but later uninstalled & intalled v4.1